# how to search entire table based on each letter

Tags: sql

I have a students table in which I store student first name,last name, rollname, dob, phone number.  My requirement is if I enter starting letter of student name, or rollname or anything, I get the data from entire table which consists the input letter.

I tried a query but I get the data only if I give the complete name or rollname.  Instead I need the data if I enter only starting letter of any field. Would you please help me.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_users 
  WHERE user_name LIKE '04' UNION 
SELECT * FROM tbl_users 
  WHERE first_name LIKE '04' UNION 
SELECT * FROM tbl_users 
  WHERE roll_num LIKE '04' UNION 
SELECT * FROM tbl_users 
  WHERE first_name LIKE '04' UNION 
SELECT * FROM tbl_users 
  WHERE last_name LIKE '04' UNION 
SELECT * FROM tbl_users 
  WHERE primary_phone_num LIKE '04'
```

Comment: you may use or operator and add % to your starting letter for example xxx like '04%'

Comment: `first_name LIKE '04'` is the same as `first_name = '04'`

Comment: You don't need the `union`. You can combine the conditions using an `OR` clause: `where first_name like '04%' or user_name like '04%' or ...`

Answer (score 4):

Use a wildcard like so:

```
... WHERE user_name LIKE '04%' ...
```

The % sign stands for any number of arbitrary characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need `%` after the search string to make that happen. Also you can add conditions with `OR` instead of multiple unions.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_users 
WHERE 
    user_name LIKE '04%' 
OR  first_name LIKE '04%' 
OR  roll_num LIKE '04%' 
OR  last_name LIKE '04%' 
OR  primary_phone_num LIKE '04%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the %-sign to define Wildcards in the like expression.

So if you want to get everything starting with 04, do:

```
... LIKE '04%'
```

So if you want to get everything ending with 04, do:

```
... LIKE '%04'
```

So if you want to get everything that has 04 somewhere, do:

```
... LIKE '%04%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_users where user_name LIKE '04%' 
UNION SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE first_name LIKE '04%'
UNION SELECT * FROM tbl_users where roll_num LIKE '04%'
UNION SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE first_name LIKE '04%'
UNION SELECT * FROM tbl_users where last_name LIKE '04%'
UNION SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE primary_phone_num LIKE '04%'
```

Please note, '04' is a starting letter of search string, that is why i am putting '%' after 04. If '04' is in middle of search string, then use '%04%'.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is using a concatenation(In SQL Server is `+`) like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM students
WHERE '|' + user_name + 
      '|' + first_name  + 
      '|' + last_name  + 
      '|' + roll_num  + 
      '|' + primary_phone_num  
      LIKE '%|04%';
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually 'LIKE' brings many more features. See this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: That is a very good example on why w3fools should never be used. That page is plain wrong. There is no such thing as a `[charlist]` in a (standard) SQL LIKE statement.